# Ubuntu pro enable fips-updates fails

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-pro

Ubuntu version: "Ubuntu 22.04 LTS"
Pro version: 31.2~22.04

I try to enable fips-updates using pro.

- `pro attach <subscritptionID>` -
  This is successfull
- `pro enable fips-updates` -
  This fails.
  Error snippet:

```
root@testmachine:~# pro enable fips-updates --assume-yes
One moment, checking your subscription first
Updating FIPS Updates package lists
Installing FIPS Updates packages
Updating standard Ubuntu package lists
Could not enable FIPS Updates.
Updating package lists
Unexpected APT error.
Failed running command 'apt-get install --assume-yes --allow-downgrades -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" ubuntu-fips' [exit(100)]. Message: E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-fips
```

[image: pro enable fips-updates]

Upon further analysis I see, the sources.list.d that gets created has the debian repo link commented, this file gets created and deleted during the process dynamically :
Check this image:   [ubuntu-fips-updates.list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r66ke.png)

Is this some bug or am I missing on anything here.
Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this issue as well. Turns out, this was due to not having the Ubuntu provided "$DISTRO-updates" apt repo configured.

In the "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/apt.py" file (provided by the ubuntu-advantage-tools package), it performs a check of the existing repos and if there's the "-updates" repo provided by Ubuntu:

```
    # Does this system have updates suite enabled?
    updates_enabled = False
    policy = run_apt_command(
        ["apt-cache", "policy"], messages.APT_POLICY_FAILED
    )
    for line in policy.splitlines():
        # We only care about $suite-updates lines
        if "a={}-updates".format(series) not in line:
            continue
        # We only care about $suite-updates from the Ubuntu archive
        if "o=Ubuntu," not in line:
            continue
        updates_enabled = True
        break
```

Up next, if the feature being enabled has "-updates" in the name and the previous check did not find a match, it comments out the repo URL entry:

```
    content = ""
    for suite in suites:
        if series not in suite:
            continue  # Only enable suites matching this current series
        maybe_comment = ""
        if "-updates" in suite and not updates_enabled:
            LOG.warning(
                'Not enabling apt suite "%s" because "%s-updates" is not'
                " enabled",
                suite,
                series,
            )
            maybe_comment = "# "
        content += (
            "{maybe_comment}deb {url} {suite} main\n"
            "# deb-src {url} {suite} main\n".format(
                maybe_comment=maybe_comment, url=repo_url, suite=suite
            )
        )
    system.write_file(repo_filename, content)
```

I'd suggest checking the repos you have on the instance. The code above looks at the output of the "apt-cache policy" command.

In my case, it's because we modify the apt repos first and later attempt to enable fips-updates, which fails.